# How do you deserialize JSON to a derived class based on request context in AspNet WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a custom JsonConverter in C# that will deserialize the request based on the role of the user.  The problem is I'm forced to use a not-so-desired static service provider to get the http context, because I cannot inject the needed services.  I'm looking for a more clean solution for this problem so any recommendations would be helpful.

Comment: It seems weird to me that this logic would be in a JsonConverter class. You could potentially create one big class with everything and deserialize all requests to that, then just pass the user info to the service from the controller (using `HttpContext.User`). If you need to limit the properties, you can create some interfaces that this big class inherits from then cast the object to the applicable interface within the service and pass that wherever you need it.

Comment: @Jesse I would like to swap the JsonConverter based on context so each converter doesn't need to know about the context.  If there is a middleware approach or a less intrusive way to handle this, would be desired.

Comment: Would a simple factory work? You pass a user role to the factory and it returns a new instance of the JsonConverter you need.

Comment: @quaabaam yes.  This is the way I'm leaning which, from what I can tell, forces the controller action to accept raw JSON and deseriaize.  If there is a way to do this in middleware, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an InputFormatter passes in an InputFormatterContext, which has the HttpContext.  This allowed me to create a JsonSeralizerSettings, add a converter (based on context) and then use those settings when invoking `JsonConvert.DeseralizerObject(...)`.  InputFormatter is part of the options object when using AddMvc.